# One donkey at a time?

Tags: idioms

Has anyone heard this expression?  If so, what does it mean?  I use it to mean that one person should speak at a time, but there is no material whatsoever on the internet.  I was trying to find its origin too.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please provide the context where you found this expression.

Comment: This wasn't by any chance a warning you saw backstage at a Tijuana bar was it?

Comment: @DigitalChris - man that sign could be taken more than a few ways.

Comment: @Rye So can the donkey …

Answer (score 4):

I hear this phrase every once in a while and in the context I hear it is usually used towards a group of men that are talking over each other.

It is a way to playfully (or sarcastically) call them out for acting like jackasses.  So saying one donkey at a time would be telling them to speak one at a time.

Comment: You must move in some very strange circles! I couldn't find a single example of this usage in the first few pages of Google results for *"one donkey at a time"*, and there are no results at all if I append *"please"* to the quoted search string, so I think it must be *very* localised.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I had an operations boss that used to use phrase all the time with our group of developers - all clowns in their 20s at the time.  I wouldn't say it is common but I hear it a few times a year.  What is funny is that the phrase seems demeaning but it is never really taken like that.

Comment: [one jackass at a time](http://books.google.it/books?id=cU80AQAAMAAJ&q=%22one+jackass+at+a+time%22&dq=%22one+jackass+at+a+time%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9TJDU-6OPKO8ygP05oCQAg&redir_esc=y) 1880

Comment: [one ass at a time](http://books.google.it/books?id=rjwmAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA44&dq=%22one+ass+at+a+time%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ejNDU5TxC-KBywOPp4GYAw&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22one%20ass%20at%20a%20time%22&f=false) 1850, I found two examples thanks to your suggestion.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - thanks for the text backing.  I find the phrase common knowledge (midwest).  I am very very surprised that it isn't found in print more... maybe because it is more of a speech phrase.

Answer (score -1):

OP's *specific* expression has no significant currency as such, but it's just one more variation on...

> *"Saving the XXX one YYY at a time"* (i.e. - we'll get where we want to end up if we do it **bit by bit**)

...where *XXX = world, planet, rainforest, etc.* and *YYY = baby, whale, tree, etc.* as appropriate. Retired donkeys often need "saving", and [Brits in particular](http://www.theguardian.com/money/2008/apr/23/charitablegiving.childprotection) support "donkey sanctuaries" around the world. There are also numerous closely-related *donkey = ass* "figurative" usages...

> *Change the world for the better by reducing the number of asses braying and stinking up the place. There is one particular ass you can get started with — right now. YOU! This practical guide blends sarcasm with wisdom to show you how you can [**Change the world — One ass at a time.**](http://store.kobobooks.com/en-gb/books/change-the-world-one-ass-at-a-time/H2l0hjBeFUq97GEwqqhXGQ?MixID=H2l0hjBeFUq97GEwqqhXGQ&PageNumber=1&utm_source=linkshare_uk&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=N0Emsn9WkGM&siteID=N0Emsn9WkGM-vPgE1A_ycHEhN7_QrQI90w)*

[Here's another example](http://www.spanx.co.uk/shop/) that "bends" the usage a bit further with *"**Shaping** the world one woman at a time"* (since they sell "figure-control" underwear, they *could* have used "ass" there! :).